# Flutter: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'msgTextStyle', when trying to refer to a variable from another variable

Tags: flutter-layout

I got error when trying to refer to a variable from another variable. In below code, error happen when refer to msgTextStyle in msgList.
Error: "Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'msgTextStyle'."
How to fix this while still keep the my intention, and what is the best practice?
Thank you!

```
    final msgTextStyle = TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        fontSize: 18,
        letterSpacing: 0.5,
        height: 2,
    );

    final msgList = Column( children: [
        Text('text 1.',style: msgTextStyle),
        Text('sync: added 4 numbers into call blacklist.',style: msgTextStyle)
    ]);
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] for a more specific help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to access an instance variable (`msgTextStyle`), in another instance variable(`msgList`) before constructor is initialized. This is disallowed as you're trying to access something that *isn't*. Move the initialization of `msgList` to constructor or `initState` or perhaps try converting `msgTextStyle` to `const`.

Comment: - initState not work because the msgTextStyle is still null at initState
- got error with const
- constructor works well
So temporary I will initialize it in constructor.
Thanks for your help!